# LWJGL: Textures drawing wider than specified

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, texture-mapping

I'm having a problem where my 128 x 128 texture is being drawn 164 x 128. Or 100x100 drawn 128x100. Have been trying to debug for days: very grateful for any help to save me pulling more hair out :)

I've been using Kevin Glass's Space Invaders 104 LWJGL code as a reference (read: copy/paste/alter/learn!) except I have no need for multiple rendering methods: I'm building a vertical scrolling shooter just using LWJGL for GL graphics and keyboard control.

The problem seems to be happening with all my "sprites" but I'm focusing/debugging my player ship sprite so I'll use that as my example here. Verified with screenshots, it's drawing the sprite wider than the pixels of the original PNG image used. At first I thought perhaps the code needed images as 2^n values, so I updated my source to a 128 x 128 pixel image: this is being drawn at 164 x 128. I recreated my image as 100 x 100, and it draws it as 128 x 100... So at least there's a consistent ratio happening! That ratio, and the fact it draws Y correct each time made me assume it was a simple error or typo somewhere...

So my first focus was this bit of code:

```java
public void draw(int x, int y) {
    // store the current model matrix
    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    // bind to the appropriate texture for this sprite
    texture.bind();

    // translate to the right location and prepare to draw
    GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);     
    GL11.glColor3f(1,1,1);

    // draw a quad textured to match the sprite
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    {
      GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
      GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
      GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, texture.getHeight()); // texture.getHeight() returns 1.0, confirmed while debugging
      GL11.glVertex2f(0, height); // height = 128px, confirmed while debugging
      GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
      GL11.glVertex2f(width,height); // width = 128px, confirmed while debugging
      GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);
      GL11.glVertex2f(width,0);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();

    // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

I've debugged this code the most, thinking this is "where the magic happens" to ensure I'm definately passing 128px for glVertex2f where appropriate, and glTexCoord2f is getting ratio 1.0 where appropriate. So my logic now is that given GL is geared for 3d and there's probably some abstraction between coordinates and actual pixels (S T vs X Y? Perhaps talking rubbish...) maybe it's the "canvas" or "display" itself that hasn't been set propertly? So the game-world/GL-world thinks the world is 1000 pixels high (for example) when the real world is drawn 800 pixels high so things are squished vertically? So my GL init code is (including Glass's comments!):

```java
public void startRendering() {

    try {
        setDisplayMode();
        Display.create();

        // grab the mouse, dont want that hideous cursor when we're playing!
            Mouse.setGrabbed(true);

            // enable textures since we're going to use these for our sprites
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND); 
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // disable the OpenGL depth test since we're rendering 2D graphics
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GL11.glOrtho(0, GAMESIZE_X, GAMESIZE_Y, 0, -1, 1);

    } catch (LWJGLException le) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    initialise();
    GameLoop();
}

private boolean setDisplayMode() {
    try {
        // get modes
        DisplayMode[] dm = org.lwjgl.util.Display.getAvailableDisplayModes(
                GAMESIZE_X, GAMESIZE_Y, -1, -1, -1, -1, 60, 60);

        org.lwjgl.util.Display.setDisplayMode(dm, new String[] {
                "width=" + GAMESIZE_X,
                "height=" + GAMESIZE_Y,
                "freq=" + 60,
                "bpp=" + org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.getDisplayMode().getBitsPerPixel() });

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unable to enter fullscreen, continuing in windowed mode");
    }

    return false;
}
```

So there's a lot of code in there that I don't fully understand, but I can't intuitively see anything that would seem to affect my problem? My correct game size is being passed at seemingly every relevant point.

Comment: I am surprised this works at all, you should set your matrix mode to `GL_MODELVIEW` after setting the projection matrix (`glOrtho (...)`). It is generally meaningless to apply transforms like `glRotatef (...)` and `glTranslatef (...)` to the projection matrix.

Comment: Also,why do you spend your time learning old,deprecated OpenGL API?Stop doing it.learn modern OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Michael: I wasn't aware this was deprecated. I'll make sure I search for some more recent example code. Do you know of any good beginner tutorials, preferably working examples?

Comment: Thanks Andon: that didn't work though: I tried with GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW) after my glOrtho line, seemed to have no effect. I tried removing the GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); at the top too, but that resulted in what looked like super zoomed in graphics...completely unrecognisable blured block colors.